# Data is rendering within Console but not showing up in Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

So I have this `Product.js` component that fetches data from my backend data. I'm trying get this component to upload JSX code by using the data I fetched. However, when the server finishes my component just returns the div and not the data within it. Here's the code:

```
import React , {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./popup.css"

function Product(){

    const [user, setUser] = useState();

    const params = useParams()
    console.log(params);

    async function getUser(id) {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/cats/${id}`)
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        setUser(params.id);
    }


    useEffect (() => {
        getUser(params.id);
    },[params.id])

    document.body.style ='#bacdd8';


    if(user){
        return(
            <div className='container'>
                 <div className='images'>
                     <img src={user.image_url} alt={user.name} />
                 </div>
                 <div className='cat'>
                     <h1>{user.name}</h1>
                     <p className='desc'>{user.description}</p>
                 </div>
            </div>
         )
        }else{
            <p>Still Loading...</p>
        }
    
}

export default Product;
```

The code above shows what I've tried which was to just use an if statement to wait for the user to pick up something then return the JSX but apparently it doesn't in time. The only proof I have that it loads is when it shows on the console. However, my conclusion is that the JSX is just loading before the data. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a typo on your part. You should be setting the user to the data you got from the server and not the params id.

```
async function getUser(id) {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/cats/${id}`)
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    setUser(params.id); <-----------------
}
```

Comment: It returns the same thing. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so at least two things must be changed in order for your code to work properly:

1. Set the user state to the actual data that you retrieved from the backend, and not the user ID you got from the route params:

```js
async function getUser(id) {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/cats/${id}`)
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    setUser(data/* param.id */); // This way you'll have a user, whenever the fetch finishes
}
```

2. Return the "loading" `<div>` correctly.

I've assembled a mock example in StackBlitz, [check it here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/example-async-loading)